# iOS augmented reality library with simple "events" system

Tags: objective-c, ios, augmented-reality

I'm looking for an iOS augmented reality library that will enable me to track a marker and either

1. Show the user a video (local or YouTube, full screen or mapped to the marker).
2. Load a regular old fashion view controller with my own code in it (like a UITableViewController).

I've been looking around and all augmented libraries I've seen seem overly complex (for what I want to do).

**Do you know of any lightweight library that will allow me to do this?** *Paid libraries are not a problem.*

This is what I've looked at:

- [Vuforia](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality)
- [String](http://www.poweredbystring.com)
- [Popcode](http://popcode.info/)
- [Metaio](http://www.metaio.com/store/)
- [3DAR](http://3dar.us/docs/)
- [Mixare](http://www.mixare.org/download/)

Thanks!

PD: I don't know how to program with Unity and a few of what look like the most promising libraries use this so those are not an option for me. I'd prefer straight up Objective-C inside XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia now has a video solution included with their Unity SDK if you are able to use Unity.  http://u3d.as/content/qualcomm-inc-/vuforia-video-playback/36v